# How to set default language to Arabic ios swift?

Tags: ios, localization, right-to-left

I'm working on a app that is 2 languages namely english and Arabic. I've written the app in english and then localized the app in Arabic. The App needs to restart when changing the Language. My only question is that how can I set the default language to arabic when installing the app for the first time.I've Tried setting the Language to arabic in Edit schemes section, But it only works for the development build not for the Distribution builds. It may be duplicate question but I've tried and not succeeded.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

For change language "on the fly" you can use [L10n-swift](http://cocoapods.org/pods/L10n-swift) pod.

But to rtl you need set semanticContentAttribute appearance for UIView

```
let isRTL = Locale.characterDirection(forLanguage: yourLanguageIdentifier) == .rightToLeft

UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = isRTL 
    ? .forceRightToLeft  
    : .forceLeftToRight
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not working for English LTR to arabic RTL

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1828/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014938), this is basically what happens:

1) iOS will search your app for the preferred languages it has on the Settings. So if your device is set to Arabic, it should go for Arabic laguage first.

2) If no languages are found, iOS will turn to the language of the app's development region, so you should set it also.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-130430-BAJJHDJH) you can find more information on how to set your app's development region (CFBundleDevelopmentRegion) on Plist file.

Comment: I've tried that as well but still no luck. It's working perfectly on simulator and on installing through the development profile but its not working on the device with distribution profile.