# How to set default language to Arabic instead of english ios swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, localization

I have developed the app having 2 language(English & Arabic). I have given screen when you can switch the language when you switch language you will need to restart the app and work proper.

But the problem is no i wants to display default language as arabic. I have set "Localization native development region (CFBundleDevelopmentRegion)" as "ar" its not works properly display weired somehow.

I event try to set AppleLanguages in NSUSerDefault but its not display my storyboard as arabic.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: refer this link => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048510/how-to-set-default-language-to-arabic-ios-swift

Comment: I think check condition in particular view controller if language is arabic or english and set layout according to langage.

Comment: Not wants to make conditions wise language, as already implemented with single storyboard and works perfect if i restart app. but on start of language i wants to set the language to arabic instead english. 

I checked above link as well and set CFBundleDevelopmentRegion but no luck

Comment: Not stored default language ar in userdefault that point check it.

Comment: I stored as well i mentioned in my question.

Comment: send your storyboard screenshot

Comment: I have attached screenshot in my question. Please check it

Comment: How to get display storyboard in arabic send screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151566/discussion-between-jay-and-nirav-patel).

Comment: @NiravPatel did you find the solution of your issue? I am facing the same case.